# Why does a simple increment not work in this InsertionSort Algorithm?

Tags: c#, sorting, insertion-sort

```
static void InsertionSort(int[] array)
    {
        int swaps = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Count(); i++)
        {
            int item = array[i];
            int index = i;
            while (index > 0 && array[index-1] > item)
            {
                array[index] = array[index - 1];
                index--;
                swaps++;
            }
            array[index] = item;
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"InsertionSorted Array: {String.Join(",",array)}, took {swaps} swaps.");
    }
```

Someone please explain to me why "swaps" always returns 0?

I've checked the placement.
Tried moving the swap++ to before the array assignment.
Even tried using ++swap (pre-increment) instead to no avail...
I just want to keep track of how many times a value gets moved to demonstrate the difference between different sorting methods.
Either I'm an idiot and need to quit now or this is beyond me.

Comment: Logical conclusion: your code never enters the loop. Set a breakpoint.

Comment: List gets sorted though...

Comment: [Seems to be working?](https://rextester.com/UKQ77053)

Comment: @MickyD Please do not direct off-topic questions to Code Review. The OP clearly thinks the code is broken "Why does a simple increment not work" and so is 100% off-topic on Code Review.

Comment: @Peilonrayz I think Micky was directing that specific part of the question to Code Review rather than the question as a whole.

Comment: @Llama Code Review gets tons of such 'helpful' suggestions where a question could be made on-topic. However the OP just posts questions verbatim. If the question isn't good enough _right now_ then don't suggest other sites.

Comment: Either way, i have removed that line and just want to know why the damn thing doesn't work. My whole department is confused.

Comment: @Llama i see you said it works so, does visual studio just hate me?

Answer (score 0):

So, Copying the whole method to a new file seems to have fixed the issue... Still do not understand why swap++; failed on me so would appreciate a valid answer but either way this problem is fixed for now.